# Sharepoint Online Provider Hosted App not working with On Prem Server

Tags: sharepoint-online, provider-hosted-app

We are creating sharepoint online provider hosted app with our on prem servers.

When creating and hosting in local PC its working fine.
Also hosted in Azure Web Apps worked fine.

When we tried to host the APP Web in our local Server, it always displays error "An error occurred while processing your request"

We tested by providing internet connections in server, but the result is same.

Followed the same steps used for hosting in local PC and Azure Web APPs. Is anything additionally needed for hosting in On Prem Servers.

Comment: Is there any solution available for the above scenario.

Answer (score 0):

For SharePoint On-Premise Server, it needs to hosted with High-Trust Provider hosted app and it needs to configure certificate for authentication, please refer the following steps for configuration:

[Create an on-premise high-trust provider-hosted app for Sharepoint 2013](https://spcaca.blogspot.com/2013/10/create-on-premise-high-trust-provider.html)

Comment: Is this steps applicable for SharePoint Online with Provider Hosted Web App on On-Premise IIS.